# Lost customization after switching the WordPress theme

Tags: customization, themes

I spent a lot of time creating a website page. Then it was not allowing me add a video, so I activated a new theme. Now every customization I did is lost. I do not even remember what the old theme was.

I cannot believe there is no way to retrieve it. Can someone help me restore my old customized theme.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not keep track of these changes without the help of special 3rd party plugins. It's too late here, but there are a some precautionary steps before switching a theme:

- Copy snippets from your current theme (functions.php etc)
- Write down all analytics and adsense tracking codes
- Copy sidebar widgets like social links, advertisements, subscription or contact forms
- Make a FULL BACKUP!!!